# Get full value from column char(1)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table for storing information about student attendance:

```
attendance
( id INT(11)
, type CHAR(1)
, for_date DATETIME
);
```

When inserting a new record, `Present, 2017-11-26`, MySQL stores `P` in `type` column.

So I'm trying to get full value Present in dashboard page with SELECT query but fails.

Is it possible to get full value without change datetype of column?

Here's what I did:

```
SELECT `id`, CONVERT(`type`, CHAR(10)) AS type, `for_date` FROM `attendance`;
```

Comment: Is the table `attendance` or `attendace`? Either way, obviously, it's not possible to retrieve data that wasn't stored in the first place. 'resent' was discarded on insert. So, if you want to return 'present', then you specifically need to tell MySQL to do so.

Comment: Name of table is `attendance`. You mean first change CHAR(10) before insert records and then return 'present' or 'absent' ?

Comment: You are assuming that, if you ask MySQL to reserve space for a single character, it will somehow ignore your instructions and will allocate more space anyway. That's not how it works, and it's a good idea—MySQL is already insane enough.

Comment: That would be one way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the full text  eg:

```
attendance
( id INT(11)
, type CHAR(16)
, for_date DATETIME
);
```

so you obtain all text using select ...

otherwise you should decode the returning values eg. using case when

```
SELECT `id`,  case when type = 'P' then 'Present' end  as my_type, `for_date` 
FROM `attendance`;
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect without need change char(1) to char(16).

Comment: @user7622967 Sure, as long as you don't start handling other values that start with `P` and are not `Present` ;-)